# Modify alpha of Surface pixels directly in pygame

Tags: python, pygame, alpha-transparency

I have a Surface in PyGame. I want to modify the alpha values of pixels directly. I've tried doing it with the various methods that access the alpha values, but they don't seem to work.

```py
from screeninfo import get_monitors
import pygame, os, numpy.random, pygame.surfarray

pygame.init()
FPS = 60
CLOCK = pygame.time.Clock()
monitor_info = get_monitors()
x = 0
y = 0
width = monitor_info[0].width
height = monitor_info[0].height
if len(monitor_info) > 1:
    if monitor_info[0].x < 0:
        x = 0
    else:
        x = monitor_info[0].width
    width = monitor_info[1].width
    height = monitor_info[1].height

os.environ['SDL_VIDEO_WINDOW_POS'] = "{},0".format(x)
pygame.display.init()
pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)
screen_info = pygame.display.Info()
screen_size = width, height
base_screen = pygame.display.set_mode(screen_size, pygame.NOFRAME)
base_screen.fill([100, 100, 100])
board_size = (int(min(width, height)*0.75), int(min(width, height)*0.75))
surface = pygame.Surface(board_size, pygame.SRCALPHA)
surface.fill([255, 255, 255, 255])
base_screen.blit(surface, (0,0))
pygame.display.flip()
pixels = numpy.random.uniform(low=0, high=255, size=(board_size[0], board_size[1], 3))
transparency = numpy.random.uniform(low=0, high=255, size=board_size).astype('uint8')
while True:
    events = pygame.event.get()
    ms = CLOCK.tick(FPS)
    print('\r             {}                  '.format(ms), end='')
    # pygame.surfarray.blit_array(surface, pixels)
    aa = pygame.surfarray.pixels_alpha(surface)
    aa = numpy.random.uniform(low=0, high=255, size=board_size).astype('uint8')
    del aa
    # for i in range(board_size[0]):
    #     for j in range(board_size[1]):
    #         a = surface.get_at((i,j))
    #         a[3] = 0
    #         surface.set_at((i,j), a)
    base_screen.blit(surface, (0,0))
    pygame.display.flip()
```

I've tried both things in the loop (pixels_array, and get_at/set_at) but neither works--the image just stays white (if I set the initial alpha to 0, it stays transparent). Does anyone know how to set per-pixel alpha values for a Surface?

Comment: Just to make sure you understand, when you say `aa = ...pixels_alpha` and `aa = numpy.random.uniform`, you do understand that second statement is not affecting the surface, right?  That fetches a set of alpha values, then throws those out and reassigns the name to the randoms from numpy.

Comment: Your commented-out `for` loop looks about right.  Did that not work?  `get_buffer` can also be used, if you can do the pixel addressing.

Comment: Looks like there's already an answer, but for my own awareness: according to the documentation the pixels_alpha call creates a reference: https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surfarray.html#pygame.surfarray.pixels_alpha. Is my second line simply re-assigning the variable's reference as opposed to modifying the reference?

Comment: Right.  Remember that names are just references to objects.  When you say `aa = ...`, that stores a new reference to a new object in `aa`.  The old reference is released.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found your problem!! The reason why you can't see alpha is:

a) you first set `surface` alpha to `255`, `surface.fill([255, 255, 255, 255])`

b) I believe `aa = pygame.surfarray.pixels_alpha(surface)` `aa = numpy.random.uniform(low=0, high=255, size=board_size).astype('uint8')` aren't working, however `pygame.surfarray.blit_array(surface, pixels)` do work (produce colours) but I don't think they have any actual Alpha.

c) you need to fill the base_screen and **THEN** blit you surface. Such a common mistake but this is the main the problem.

And finally, Tim Robert's comment about the for loop, will definitely get you your alpha!

Here is it re-written to work (without `screeninfo` as I don't have that library currently):

```
import pygame, os, numpy.random, pygame.surfarray
from random import randint

pygame.init()
FPS = 60
CLOCK = pygame.time.Clock()
x = 50
y = 50
width = 500
height = 500

os.environ['SDL_VIDEO_WINDOW_POS'] = "{},0".format(x)
#pygame.display.init(), don't actually need this
pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)
screen_info = pygame.display.Info()
screen_size = width, height
base_screen = pygame.display.set_mode(screen_size, pygame.NOFRAME)
base_screen.fill([100, 100, 100])
board_size = (int(min(width, height)*0.75), int(min(width, height)*0.75))
surface = pygame.Surface(board_size, pygame.SRCALPHA)
surface.fill([255, 0, 0]) ###could also be surface.fill([255,0,0,255]) to set the whole surface's alpha straight up if you didn't want to change each pixel later

while True:
    #just so you can quit this program
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            raise SystemExit()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_q:
                pygame.quit()
                raise SystemExit()
                
    ms = CLOCK.tick(FPS)

    for i in range(board_size[0]):
         for j in range(board_size[1]):
             a = surface.get_at((i,j))
             a[3] = randint(0, 128)#OR SET TO REQUIRED ALPHA VALUE
             surface.set_at((i,j), a)

    ##################################################
    base_screen.fill([100, 100, 100]) #NEED TO DO THIS
    ##################################################

    base_screen.blit(surface, (0,0))
    pygame.display.flip()
```

(by the way, I used red as the second surface colour as I thought it would stand out better)

**Edit**

As Eternal Ambiguity stated in the comments, here is the much, **much** faster version, in place of the `for` loops:

```
aa = pygame.surfarray.pixels_alpha(surface)
aa[:] = numpy.random.uniform(low=0, high=255, size=board_size).astype('uint8')
del aa
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I wound up using a modified version where I kept the `pygame.surfarray.pixels_alpha` usage and assigned the numpy random grid to a second variable. Then I could loop through and assign to the pixel array without running randint literally millions of times.

Comment: Just for awareness - I was able to make it even faster by modifying in-place with a[:] = b[:], where a is the pixels_array and b is the numpy random array.

Comment: @EternalAmbiguity NICE!!! I assume like this? 
`for i in range(board_size[0]):
        pygame.surfarray.pixels_alpha(surface)[i] = numpy.random.uniform(low=0, high=255, size=board_size).astype('uint8')[i]
`.  
Or is it more like: 
`i +=1
 if i >= board_size[0]:
        i = -1
pygame.surfarray.pixels_alpha(surface)[i] = numpy.random.uniform(low=0, high=255, size=board_size).astype('uint8')[i]
`. I was just wondering as I don't use numpy :)

Comment: It's actually much simpler - just `aa = pygame.surfarray.pixels_alpha(self.image)` then `aa[:] = numpy.random.uniform(low=0, high=255, size=self.board_size).astype('uint8')` and finally `del aa`. With the `[:]` I modify the value `aa` points to--no looping necessary.

Comment: @EternalAmbiguity Ahh, the `[:]` makes a copy and passes it the Numpy array, neat.
I have learnt quite a bit with this question, so thanks a ton mate, really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

[`pygame.Surface.blit()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit) does not replace the pixels in the target surface with the source surface. It mixes (blends) the pixels of the surfaces. Actually you are blending the new surface with the old previous surface every frame. This means that the area of the surface appears uniformly colored within milliseconds. You have to clear the screen in every frame:

```py
while True:
    # [...]

    base_screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    base_screen.blit(surface, (0,0))
    pygame.display.flip()
```

---

Minimal example:

[image]

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()

width, height = 200, 200
base_screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

board_size = (int(min(width, height)*0.75), int(min(width, height)*0.75))
surface = pygame.Surface(board_size, pygame.SRCALPHA)
surface.fill([255, 0, 0])

for x in range(board_size[0]):
    for y in range(board_size[1]):
        a = surface.get_at((x, y))
        a[3] = round(y / board_size[1] * 255)
        surface.set_at((x, y), a)

run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(100)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
                
    base_screen.fill((100, 100, 100))
    base_screen.blit(surface, surface.get_rect(center = base_screen.get_rect().center))
    pygame.display.flip()
```